# exact copy of amplifier stages

Tags: amplifier

My stage 1 amplifier alone is perfectly bias and the q point is in the middle of the load line. The collector voltage is around at the middle of the supply voltage (to be precise, around 24 volts and supply voltage is at 48 volts). Now when we add another exact copy of stage 1 and attached it to stage 1, the q point of the stage 2 suddenly misaligned from the middle point of the load line (it went from 24 volts to 11 volts). Why is that so? It should be that the original bias condition and q point must be inherited since both stages are exact copies of each other (like identical twins)

[image]

which results to severe distortion

[image]

Comment: It looks like you're missing the "junction dot" at the crossover where R8, R9, Q2 base and the coupling capacitor come together.

Comment: @DaveTweed i just retried it, its not missed

Comment: Does Spice model the breakdown of a Vceo=40V transistor on a 48V supply?

Comment: yes it is at 74.01 volts specifically

Comment: A quick inspection of the bias resistors shows they are way off on both stages. The current in the divider chain should be about 10x the base current, so that the divider accurately controls Vb. It doesn't. If it did, Vb would be about 3V, Ve about 2.3. With Re(R2)=82, that means Ie over 25ma, or >50V across Rc(R1). Re-bias and try again!

Comment: I agree with Brian. The data sheet gives hFE as 100 to 300. At 100, Ic=7mA & Vc=34V. At 300, Ic=14mA & Vc=20V ... too sensitive to hFE.  What current gain is your Spice model assuming for the two transistors?

Comment: Someone tries to actually design a circuit and people downvote them... what a nice community we have here!

Comment: @ChrisStratton i agree, downvoting to circuit being design by newbies gives no encouragement and no room for improvement

Comment: @BrianDrummond why choose Vb to be at 3V?

Comment: There's no magic about 3V as such, but your choice of R3 and R4 would give close to 3V if it was working correctly as a voltage divider (i.e. if you disconnected Q1, or if R2 was appropriately rated to keep Ib down to a value suitable for R3, R4 - which would reduce Ic) These are all interdependent. A reasonable step by step guide to setting them is http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/amplifier/amp_2.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Q point is the *quiescent point*, i.e., the operating currents and voltages ***when no signal is present***.

A simulator should give you the DC solution for the circuit.  Check that to see if the collector voltages are equal.

Or, zero the signal source and check your collector voltages.  They *should* be the same.

If they aren't, check your net list for an error.

When there are *large* signals present, the DC (time average) voltage on the collector can be very different from the Q point voltage due to non-linearity, clipping, etc.

UPDATE:  Re the bias network others are pointing out, in a [previous post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/49624/amplifier-quality-waveform-for-different-transistors/49633#49633), I provided you with an equation for the bias current and we specifically talked about bias stability against variations in beta.  Let's check your circuit against that.

Recall the equation:

\$I_C =  \dfrac{V_{BB} - V_{BE}}{\frac{R_{BB}}{\beta}+\frac{R_{e}}{\alpha}}\$

The key for stability is to have the right most term in the denominator much larger than the leftmost term.

According to your schematic:

\$R_{BB}= 28k \Omega \$

So, the leftmost term is:

\$\dfrac{28k \Omega}{200} = 140 \Omega \$

But the rightmost term is just about 82 ohms when it should at least 1400 ohms for a roughly 10% variance of DC collector current due to variations in transistor beta.  A simple partial fix is to try using 43k and 3k in your divider circuit.

You've been *given* the tools to use so *use them*!

Comment: tnk u so much. i just zeroed the source voltage and collector voltages aren't the same. ill update you

Comment: i just fixed it, multisim appears to be sensitive in nodes.. what simulator do you recommend?

Comment: how did u know that beta is 200?

Comment: @vvavepacket, I just picked the value of 200 as a guess at the typical value for this transistor.  According to the data sheet, the beta can range from 100 to 300.  On another note, have you considered using a npn-pnp CE cascade with direct coupling? http://i.stack.imgur.com/TOfod.png

Answer (score 1):

What kind of capacitor is ... argh ... you didn't put a component designator on it other than "1".  If this is a electrolytic, it may be conducting backwards, or leaking.

From a quick look, R2 seems too low.  That will make setting the bias point open loop as you are doing tricky and unpredictable.  The bias point would be more stable if the top end of R3 went to the collector instead of the positive supply since that would provide some DC feedback.  Of course R3 and R4 then need to be adjusted accordingly since they will be dividing down about half the supply voltage instead of the full supply voltage to make the base voltage.

C3 is way higher than necessary.  The rolloff frequency of the filter formed by R5 and C3 is only 240 mHz.  It would be better to aim for around 10 Hz even for "hi-Fi" audio.

You seem to be trying for a gain of about 48 per stage.  I would try to limit each single-transistor stage to about 10.  That will make it easier to keep things predictable and invite less distortion.  Why do you want so much gain anyway?  You are starting with 400 mVpp apparently, and just the supply alone limits your output to 48 Vpp.  That's a total gain of only 120, which could be done nicely with two stages with a gain of 11 each.